# Hosting Asp.net Core 6 Web API with SSL on a Specific Port

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have developed Asp.net Core 6 Web Api and want to host it on my Windows server on a specific port that has SSL installed.  Here is what I have done so far -

- I have an SSL certificate which I added in the Personal store using certificate manager.
- I installed this SSL certificate on Port 10001 and it got added successfully.
- I created a subdomain and pointed it to this web server.

I want to run this API as an EXE hosted with Kestrel.  I tried -

- app.run("https://api.xxxxxx.com:10001")
- I get an error that SSL Certificate could not be located.

Please help me with how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful if you provided the commands used for adding the port reservation and how you added the certificate to Windows, but anyways, my personal experience dealing with self-hosted apps and SSL is the following:

- Add the certificate used for https to the Windows Certificates Store -> Local Computer (this is important, don't use the Current User store) -> Personal store
- If NOT using localhost as the server address, as in your case, a Url mapping must be done with netsh.exe (with an elevated command window):

  netsh.exe http add urlacl url=https://+:10001/ user=Users (*)
- Next, make a port reservation using also netsh.exe:

  netsh.exe http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:10001 certhash=[your cert hash here] appid={your app id here}

(*) If your Windows language is other than English, use the name of the translated Users group. For instance, in spanish it would be "Usuarios".

If all these procedures are done correctly, you should be able to launch a server that binds to the specified port with https enabled.

Good luck